# Error while trying to activate matching rule

Tags: duplicate-value, criteria, criteria-filter, findduplicates, duplicate-matching-rule

[image]I've been struggling with activating a matching rule but I keep getting this error I can't get rid of:

[image]

I have attached my matching rule with requested criteria + duplicate rule as per the requirements I got. [image]

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: How many account records do you have in your org? Have you run a SOQL query to identify the number of accounts where the account name, Record Type and Postal Code are all the same?

Comment: I've cleaned up the org so now I have zero accounts. No other type of records either.

Comment: did you hard delete from recycle bin?